# In Wurm Online, what's the best way to get your Fight Skill up to 20?

Tags: wurm-online

Use what weapons?  Use enchants?  Use practice dummies?  Use help from more advanced fighters?

What else can I do to improve my Fight Skill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to improve your fighting skill. [Wurmpedia refers to them as the Safe Way and the Dangerous Way](http://www.wurmonline.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tips_for_Skills#Fighting), so I will do the same.

## The Safe Way

Create a practice dummy and equip a shaft or some other weapon, as long as it isn't a true weapon such as a sword. You'll destroy the practice dummy too quickly in that case and waste a good weapon by wearing it down.

Beat the poor doll senseless, but make sure you keep its damage below 20 at all times so as not to destroy the dummy's body along with its simple mind.

Wurmpedia recommends in their [fighting guide](http://www.wurmonline.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fighting_Guide) that you grind like this until your Fight Skill hits 10, and then proceeding on to...

## The Dangerous Way

Go hunting! That's all there is to it, actually. If you're going at this straight from the beginning instead of being bored with the dummy, you'll want to start with simple farm animals(i.e. pigs, pheasants, roosters, bulls, cows). Around Fight Skill at level 10, you'll want to go hunting wolves; be warned, they will attack the legs quite often, so equip leg protection to save health.

Pheasants, in particular, are excellent targets; they will not follow you when you back away from a fight, giving you time heal and regain stamina.

**Another Tip**: Casting the enchantments Circle of Cunning and Wind of Ages may help speed up the rate at which your skill level improves. The former will improve the skill gain per usage of the weapon, while the latter will take away the last 2 seconds of the weapon's base swing time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I kind get most of that.  Does the weapon you use matter?  And people report that Wind of Ages may actually slow skill gain for most things -- does that apply to fighting?  What about fighting e.g. scorps and crocs with assistance instead of wolves and lions alone?